# app.config file in C# for SQL Server 2005 in VS 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have C# .net project with SQL Server 2008 written in Visual Studio 2008. There I used the following connection string to connect with SQL Server:

```
string connectionString = 
    @"server=HASIBPC\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security=SSPI; 
      database=XPHotelManagementDatabase";
```

But problem is every time I take my application from one computer to another computer I need to change the `server` in `connectionString`. I don't want to change this manually. I want this will change dynamically. How will I do that using `app.config`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample;

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\PressbyranDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

Note that `Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;` attribute as your SQL Server and Server Instance name. Also, you do not need to restore your database from machine to machine if you use the `AttachDbFilename=` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

If the database is local with the application you can use `LocalHost` in your connection string assuming all other information is the same.

Eg:

```
string connectionString = @"server = LOCALHOST\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security = SSPI; database = XPHotelManagementDatabase";
```

Comment: FYI, I believe you can also use `.\SQLEXPRESS`

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use app config to store a connection string - you could just pass a dynamically generated connection string to the SqlConnection constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from LOCALHOST and "."
 You can

1. use "server = 127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS"
2. Add an alias to the SQL Server Configuration Manager and use that in your string
3. add `127.0.0.1 foo` to your hostsfle and use it e.g. "server = FOO\SQLExpress"
4. Mange the connection in the machine config