# app.config file in C# for SQL Server 2005 in VS 2008

Tags: c#, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [app.config  file in C# for MS SQL Server 2005 in VS 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533279/app-config-file-in-c-for-ms-sql-server-2005-in-vs-2008)

I have C# .net project with SQL Server 2008 written in Visual Studio 2008. There I used the following connection string to connect with SQL Server:

```
string connectionString = @"server = HASIBPC\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security = SSPI; database = XPHotelManagementDatabase";
```

But problem is every time I take my application from one computer to another computer I need to change the "server" in "connectionString". I dont want to change this manually. I want this will change dynamically. How will I do that using app.config?

Comment: Exact duplicate. Something's up, what's the deal?

Comment: Actually my internet connection was disconnected. And I cant understand the question was submitted. And I submitted the question again. I'm sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in your app.config:

```
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
      <add key="server" value="HASIBPC\SQLEXPRESS" />
   <appSettings>
</configuration>
```

And then in your code, access it using:

```
return ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["server"].ToString();
```

Comment: The OP asked the same question [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533279/app-config-file-in-c-for-ms-sql-server-2005-in-vs-2008)

Comment: I'm sorry for this. My internet connection got disconnected when I submitted the question and I submitted this question again.