# Use Connection string in app.config C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, app-config

I am using Visual Studio 2005 C#. Designing a mobile App for handheld scanners. At the moment I'm declaring a connection string on every form I have. I do not want to do this. I know you can do it app.config file.

I am struggling to understand how the app.config file works. I have read forums and stackoverflow posts, but I just can't find it. Can someone please help me with this?

Example: [app.config file in C# for SQL Server 2005 in VS 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533310/app-config-file-in-c-sharp-for-sql-server-2005-in-vs-2008)

But where is the app.config file?

Using:
Visual Studio 2005
.net 2.0

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

app.config file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyString" 
         connectionString="User Id=christob;Password=CHRISTOB;Host=poseidon;Pooling=true;Min Pool Size=0;Max     Pool Size=100;Connection Lifetime=0;Port=1523;Sid=GLODCQA"
         providerName="CoreLab.Oracle" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>



using System.Configuration;

private void btnExit_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sTemp = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyString"].ConnectionString;
etc........
    }
```

Error:

Error   1   Deployment and/or registration failed with error: 0x8973190e. Error writing file '%csidl_program_files%\hhrcv_app\system.dll'. Error 0x80070070: There is not enough space on the disk.
    Device Connectivity Component

Why do I get this error? I only get it when I use systems.configuration; But i have to?

Comment: What project type are you using in Visual Studio?  If it's any type of application project, you should be able to add a new item to the project and select "Application Configuration File" as that item.  That file could then contain configurable values for the application which don't require a re-build, and the file would be deployed alongside the application in the build output.

Comment: if you right click your project, Select 'Add' and 'New Item', then select an Application Configuration File

Comment: Note that if you don't already have and don't want to use a config file (if it's a big deal in your deployment process, for example) then another option for you may be to declare a single static connection string in the application instead of one on every form.  All the forms could just use the static one.

Comment: @David Yes, That is what I've been reading...
Smart DEvice > Pocket Pc 2003 or Windows CE 5.0 > Device application.
SO when i right click my solution > add > new item > (it should be here , but its not )

Comment: @WernervandenHeever: Interesting.  I'm not familiar with Pocket PC or Windows CE project templates.  Definitely look around the available items to see if one can be added, it might be in a different pane in the interface.  You might also try just adding a text file called `App.Config` manually and putting XML config data in that file to see if the build/deploy process includes it.  If there really is no option for a config file in that project type then perhaps a static connection string will get you where you need to be much more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have a template for it, you can create the file manually. The default App.config file that Visual Studio generates contains the following text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
</configuration>
```

Create a text file called App.config in your solution directory with the above text in it, then add it to your project as an existing item.

Answer (score 0):

It's a file you can add to your project.

Add => New Item => Visual C# Items => General => Application Configuration File